# Shared workspace for Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have an RCP application which has two views. In both the views, the user can create projects and files. these files will be stored as XML in the workspace.

**Workspace**
 1.) project1 
      -- file1.xml
      -- file2.xml
      -- .project
 2.) Project2
      -- file1.xml
      -- file2.xml
      -- .project
In eclipse rcp application, a workspace can be used by only one application instance at the same time. These configuration XML files contains are of size(<1 mb size).

**Now my requirement is to use a shared workspace for different instances of the same RCP application running from different machines so that the changes that one person makes will be accessible to the other person. How can I achieve the same?**

Answer (score 0):

As you already said this isn't possible, Eclipse has no support for sharing a workspace.

Eclipse does support various source control systems like SVN or GIT which allow users to check in changes to a central repository. Doing this is a manual processs.

To do things automatically you would have to use some sort of server, perhaps a database that the RCP can communicate with.